# how to create data volume from image for use in nginx container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an image (not container) which has the data baked in at /store. The image does not do anything else, it is only a vessel for holding the data in. I want to create a docker-compose file so that my nginx container has access to everything in /store at /usr/share/nginx/html

Do I need to make an intermediary container first? I am not sure how the docker-compose file would look. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for managing that would probably do use a docker volume to store you're /store datas.
You can do it once by creating a container from that image, mount an empty docker volume in it, and then copy the content of /store in the external docker volume.

If you still need to use the /store from an existing image you will need to instanciate a container from if and retrieve the exposed volume from your nginx container. (using volume_from). In this case both containers would need to be on the same host.

Comment: thanks, but how do I specify that /store should be mounted at /usr/share/nginx/html in the nginx container?

Comment: if you really need to keep having the data read from the image (and not from a docker volume stored externally), and if you need to keep different path you could mount /store in your container and make a symlink of /usr/share/nginx/html to /store in your nginx container at startup

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick step process:

```
docker run -v nginx-store:/store --rm store true

docker run -v nginx-store:/usr/share/nginx/html -d --name nginx nginx
```

The first run creates a named volume `nginx-store` from the contents of your `store` image (this happens any time you mount an empty volume in a container), and immediately exits and deletes the container.

The second run uses that named volume with the future nginx containers. To modify the `nginx-store` volume in the future, you can run any side container that mounts it with a similar `-v nginx-store:/target` flag.

Comment: Not a comment to your answer, but merely to Docker volumes in general... The difference in behaviour between the first and second command makes me vomit. What if I *mean* to use an empty volume? I would expect to see an empty `/store` inside the container on the first command, really.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [local-persist volume plugin](https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist) as follows:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - data:/usr/share/nginx/html 
volumes:
  data:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data
```

Obviously other volume plugin types might offer more flexibility.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to consider bake `/store` inside your nginx container. It will reduce number of mounted volumes and thus simplify overall structure. And maybe improves performance.

You could do it in several ways:

1. Use you data image as base for your nginx image. In this case you will need to write Dockerfile for nginx but it's not very difficult.
2. You can extract `/store` from your data image by creating container with `true` endpoint and `docker cp` desired data. Then copy it to your nginx image.